# jQuery Encrypted API - XML display

Tags: xml, api, jquery, get

Is there a way to parse XML from an encrypted API via jQuery?  Would I need to use ajax?  Anyone have any examples?  This is what I have:

```
http://www.mysite.com/net/WebService.aspx?Login=email@email.com&
EncryptedPassword=XXXXX&EDI_Name=Generic\Products& 
SELECT_Columns=p.ProductCode,pe.ProductPrice
```

This is the returned XML I would like to also return and parse into a table or something:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Export>
<Products_Joined>
  <productcode>PRODUCT 1</productcode>
  <productprice>1500</productprice>
</Products_Joined>
</Export>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming you have access to run javascript on the server, something like this:

```
var url = 'http://www.mysite.com/net/WebService.aspx?...';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        var table = $('#mytable-id');
        $(xml).find('Products_Joined').each(function(){
            var product = $(this),
                code = product.find('productcode').text(),
                price = product.find('productprice').text();

            $('<tr />').append('<td>' + code + '</td>')
                .append('<td>' + price + '</td>')
                .appendTo(table);
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok this is a good start.  It doesn't seem to work with the API.  However I tried it with a direct URL of an XML and it still didnt work.  http://www.basequipment.com/v/newsite/test.xml.xml

Comment: The script must be on the server or you will face a same origin conflict. Otherwise you will need to make a proxy to download the xml and serve your local project. Also see [jsonp](http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/).